# Is it possible to associate an existing working folder with a new repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

We had a series of unfortunate events with our VisualSVN server yesterday and we are trying to get back on track today.  I have recreated the repository as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293692/recreating-svn-repository) stackoverflow post.

We recreated the repository with a co-workers working copy folder (svn-export, svn-import).  But now when he tries to update we get an error message about the UUID's not matching.  Can I update his working copy to get the UUID's to match or are we going to have to now delete his working copy and recreate that as well?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone will have to check out fresh working copies and manually copy over changed files that they want to preserve from their old WCs to the new.

Going forward, please please PLEASE back up your repository (via scheduled dumps or hotcopies) so that your history will not be lost in the event of another…unfortunate event.

Answer (score 0):

would **svn relocate** do the trick?

If everything was imported into the repository and you wouldn't lose anything, I'd play it safe and just re check it out (in a new directory).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to fix and match the UUID's up.

But: what's so tricky about recreating his working copy? A simple checkout will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone will have to check out their working copies again.  We have experienced this before.

For those that were negligent in frequently checking in they should check out a new working directory in parallel, do a directory diff with the old working copy, review the changes, and copy from the old working directory to the new working directory any changes that they are comfortable with.